# Trouble configuring MySQL server for Play framework 1.3.0 web app

Tags: java, mysql, playframework-1.x

I have received the error below when trying to open my web app at localhost:9000 after attempting to connect to my MySQL server (which I can confirm is running at port 3306, hostname 127.0.0.1, user base, pass base, using the database base). I am using the below configuration in my configuration file

db.default=mysql://base:base@localhost/base.

I understand that this is a very simple configuration error, but I am very new to both MySQL and Play framework, and it is rather difficult to find examples of properly configuring this release of Play. I have read the associated documentation on database configurations and https://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2.7/guide1. Do I need to adjust some part of the associated Java application file? Below is the stack trace. I would really appreciate any help.

```
13:51:54,048 ERROR ~

@78ikb4bdh
Internal Server Error (500) for request GET /

Database error
A database error occured: Cannot connected to the database[default], Could not create connection to database server.

play.exceptions.DatabaseException: Cannot connected to the database[default], Could not create connection to database server.
    at play.db.DBPlugin.onApplicationStart(DBPlugin.java:196)
    at play.plugins.PluginCollection.onApplicationStart(PluginCollection.java:515)
    at play.Play.start(Play.java:537)
    at play.Play.detectChanges(Play.java:641)
    at play.Invoker$Invocation.init(Invoker.java:198)
    at Invocation.HTTP Request(Play!)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server.
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor21.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.Java:409)
    at com.mysql.Jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java: 384)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1013)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:987)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.Java:973)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:918)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2588)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewlO(ConnectionImpl.Java:2321)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:832)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.Java:46)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor18.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at Java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:409)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:417)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonregisteringDriver.connect(NonregisteringDriver.Java:344)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.Java:677)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:228)
    at play.db.DBPlugin.onApplicationStart(DBPlugin.java:125)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getserverCharacterEncoding(ConnectionImpl.Java:3307)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendConnectionAttributes(MysqllO.java:1985)
    at com.mysql.Jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakewithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1911)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1288)
    at com.mysql.Jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2506)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2539)
    ... 16 more
```

Comment: this question is a mess. there is no stack trace at the bottom

Comment: I appreciate any advice on formatting. I'm a new user so I'm not allowed to post images, the stack trace is the hyperlink on the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend taking a look at the following documentation:
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2.7/configuration#db.url

> For a local MySQL5 database:
>
> ```
> db=mysql:user:pwd@database_name
> ```

Or in your case,

```
db.default=mysql:base:base@localhost/base
```